# Android capture result of system USB permission dialog

Tags: android

I'm attempting to sort out permission dialogs for USB connectivity on Android.

I have a `device_filter.xml` registered on Android.

My Android manifest contains a `metadata` tag for `device_filter.xml` and also registers intent filters for `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED`.

When I connect a USB device, the system will automatically display a permission dialog. The issue however is that `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` is fired immediately, before the user makes a selection on the system-generated permission dialog. I'd like to get the result of the system permission dialog. If I check `UsbManager.HasPermission` right away, it returns false and if I follow up with a `UsbManager.RequestPermission(..)` call, two dialogs are displayed.

My current workaround is based off on:

[How to handle the Usb Permission Dialog Event on android when using the "device filter" solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544940/how-to-handle-the-usb-permission-dialog-event-on-android-when-using-the-device)

where I check `UsbManager.HasPermission(..)` repeatedly, otherwise timing out after some period of time. This isn't the best, because I don't get an explicit *denied* request from the system. As one edge case, the user could have just not touched the dialog during the timeout period and this workaround would incorrectly assume that they denied it.

Is there a way to get the result of system dialog permission? I'd like to register a broadcast receiver for it, unfortunately, it looks Android does not specify an Intent action when it [sends the permission intent result](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/usb/UsbDialogHelper.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=243?gsn=sendPermissionDialogResponse&gs=KYTHE%3A%2F%2Fkythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain%2F%2Fmain%3Flang%3Djava%3Fpath%3Dcom.android.systemui.usb.UsbDialogHelper%2370d4df7458e2166f7d7b2dc9b2d5871d27baad2e24da89816522bd852a81ca89).